# should database contain some business logics?

Tags: database, database-design

Let's say I have an item `A,B,C` in `Table1`. 
They all have attributes `f1`. However, `A` and `B` has `f2` which does not apply to `C`. 
`Table1` would be designed as:

```
    itemName      f1       f2 
------------------------------------
       A           100     50
       A           43      90
       B           66      10
       C           23
```

There would be another table `Table2` contains all the possible value of `f2`:

```
    itemName      f2(possible value)      
------------------------------------
       A           50      
       A           90
       A           77
       B           10
```

Let's say now i want to add an record with the highest value of `f2` into `Table1`,depends on the `iteaName`. Things working fine for `A` and `B`. But in the case of `C`, when i loop through `Table2`, since there is no record of `C` in `Table2`, I cannot distinguish if it's a corrupted table or the fact that `C` just does not have attribute `f2`.

The only twos ways i can think of to solve this issue is:
1. Adding a constraint in the code, like:

```
   if (iteaName == C )
       "Do not search Table2"
   else (search Table2)
       if (No record)
          return "Corrupted Table"
```

Or 
2. Adding another bool field `"having_f2"`in `Talbe1` to helping identifying that `f2` does not apply to C.

The above is just an example of where to put such business logic constraints, in the DB or in the code.

Can you give me more opinions on the tradeoff between the above two ideology? In another word, which one makes more sence.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is basically a **field validation** (*"if `MyModel` can have property f2 set to NULL (inexistent)"*), I would say, you must do that in a validator of your model.

Only if that is impossible, add some columns to model tables.

The rule I use is the following: database is used to store model data. You should try to store nothing else, except data, if possible. In your case `has_f2` is not a data, but a business rule.

Of course, there are exceptions to this rule. For example, sometimes business logic must be controlled by the user and in this case it is perfectly ok to store it in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your second proposal: you typically can also just query for a ~NULL value in the table, which would be the same as adding and setting a boolean attribute (would be better considering redundancy). This would also be the way to detect if the table is "corrupt". However, you can also start your query by collecting all "itemName" entries from table2, possibly building an intersection with table1 and inserting the cases of interest into table1:

```
1.) Intersect the "itemName" from table1 and table2 => table3
2.) Join the table3 and table2 on "itemName", "f2" => insert each tuple into table1
```

Alternatively, you can also split table1 into two tables { "itemName", "f1" } and { "itemName", "f2" } which would eliminate your problem.